# Is there a way to get the URL of a site opened in a browser in app mode using Microsoft's UI Automation API?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, browser, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

Using the Windows Automation UI (System.Windows.Automation) in C# I can get the URL from a browser window:

```cs
return parent?.FindFirst
(
  TreeScope.Descendants,
  new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit)
);
```

However, if the website is opened by the browser in "app mode" (Chrome) this fails because the URL bar is hidden. Is there a way to get the URL of a site using MS UI Automation when the URL bar is hidden?

To open a URL in Chrome in app mode see: https://superuser.com/questions/33548/starting-google-chrome-in-application-mode

Comment: How do you start "app mode" exactly? Otherwise, with UIA, you can always use Inspect tool from Windows SDK (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) or more recent Accessibility Insights (https://accessibilityinsights.io/) to check what is "seen" by UIA before writing any code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at both of those. Instructions on opening a URL in Chrome in app mode are here: https://superuser.com/questions/33548/starting-google-chrome-in-application-mode

Comment: Ok I managed to do it with `chrome.exe --app=https://www.stackoverflow.com --new-window` and in this case the first child of the top window (of type "document") supports the ValuePattern (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.valuepattern) and the value it exhibits is the url.

Comment: Hey @SimonMourier I'm looking at the same area, but do you know what would cause the ValuePattern to only work sometimes? I'm seeing this exception: `Unsupported Pattern.   at System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.GetCurrentPattern` but only sometimes. But other times I can successfully retrieve the URL

Comment: @thomas - If patterns support changes, it probably means you're looking at an element that is not always of the same type.